# Bubbles are not withstanding till end of the visualization - Google Motion Bubble Chart

Tags: javascript, java, charts, google-visualization

I was trying to populate my data with google visualization bubble motion chart (referred [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/motionchart#example)). I have created a dynamic web project, added the Chart.html file in WebContent folder. Exported the project as a .war file. I have deployed the same .war file to Apache Tomcat. Now, the chart is running, but all the bubbles are not withstanding till the end of the visualization. Once they stop moving, they are disappearing. Only the last bubble remains till the end of the visualizaton.

This is the script I have used -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["motionchart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Product'); 
      data.addColumn('date', 'Date'); 
       data.addColumn('number', 'Days'); 
    data.addRows([
                  ['Cards',new Date (1989,0,1), 120] ,
                  ['Home Loan', new Date (1990,1,1), 67],
                  ['Personal Loan', new Date (1991,2,1), 89] 
                ]);


    var chart = new google.visualization.MotionChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    chart.draw(data, {width: 1200, height:600});

  }
</script>
```

Can anyone please help me out of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need at least two data points for each category (from / to)...

The bubbles remain using this example...

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages:["motionchart"]
});
function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Product');
  data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Days');
  data.addRows([
    ['Cards',new Date (1989,0,1), 120],
    ['Home Loan', new Date (1990,1,1), 67],
    ['Personal Loan', new Date (1991,2,1), 89],
    ['Cards',new Date (1990,0,1), 200],
    ['Home Loan', new Date (1991,1,1), 87],
    ['Personal Loan', new Date (1992,2,1), 140]
  ]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.MotionChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, {width: 1200, height:600});
}
```

Comment: Thats a better point @WhiteHat, but even though I have used the same code you have given and still am getting the same issue. But thank you for giving some time for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution!!! The problem was in the Date object in data.addRows().
I changed it to -

```
data.addRows([
['Cards',new Date (1989,0,1), 120],
['Home Loan', new Date (1990,1,1), 67],
['Personal Loan', new Date (1991,2,1), 89],
['Cards',new Date (1995,0,1), 200],
['Home Loan', new Date (1995,0,1), 87],
['Personal Loan', new Date (1995,0,1), 140]  ]);
```

What ever the data we insert in to the rows, finally the ending date of all the entities should be same [new Date (1995,0,1)].